# How do I calculate the remainder of $13^{13^{13}} \mod 22$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have been looking into number theory, but I cannot get the hang of calculating remainders of numbers with multiple exponents such as

$$ 13^{13^{13}} \mod 22 $$

So far I have calculated that $13 \mod 22$ has a period of 9 and that $13 \mod  9$ has a period of 3 and $13 \mod 3$ has a period of 1. But I don't know what to do next...

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you

Comment: $13^5 = -1 \pmod{22}$. Also, _modules_ isn't the right tag here; it should be _modular arithmetic_.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607498/last-two-digits-of-171717/607509#607509

Answer (score 2):

Using [Euler's totient Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), $\phi(22)=10$

So, $$13^{13^{13}}\equiv 13^{13^{13}\pmod{10}}\pmod{22}$$

Again as $\phi(10)=4$ and $13\equiv1\pmod4,$,
 $$13^{13}\equiv13^{1}\pmod{10}\equiv3$$

Answer (score 2):

This is not to supplant lab's answer but to explain something as you appear to be a novice.

First show that
$$13^{10} \equiv 1 \mod 22$$
This is where you use $\phi(22)=10$

Next show that $13 ^4 \equiv 1 \mod 10$

So
$$ 13^{13}= 13 \cdot 13^{12} = 13 \cdot \left(13^4\right)^3 \equiv 13 \equiv 3 \mod 10 $$
So 
$$ 13^{13}= 10 a + 3 $$

Hence 
$$13^{{13}^{13}} = 13 ^{10 a + 3} = \left(13^{10}\right)^a \cdot 13^3 \equiv 13^3 \mod 22$$
Calculating this we get
$$13^{{13}^{13}} \equiv 19 \mod 22$$

Comment: And how do I show that $ 13^4 \equiv 1 (mod\space 10) $? I know it's a silly question but I really need it because I am very bad at  this

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

A naive approach:

$$13^2=169=15=-7\pmod{22}\implies 13^3=13\cdot(-7)=-91=-3\pmod{22}\implies$$

$$\implies 13^4=-39=5\pmod{22}\implies 13^5=65=-1\pmod{22}$$

From the above, $\;13^{10}=1\pmod {22}\;$